# Efficient way of importing an Excel doc into Zeppelin to build a temp table

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have two excel documents (one is related to income and the other is for demographics) that I'm working with to build out tables to run queries on existing data. The file with income data was pretty straight forward with three different columns so I was able to build out the table in two steps like this:

(1)

```
%spark.sql
create table temp_db_income (State string, MEN_INC varchar(255), WOM_INC varchar(255))
```

(2)

```
%spark.sql
insert into table temp_db_income
values
('AL', '53690', '50770'),
('AK', '76560', '72865')
```

However, the data for demographics is much more detailed, and contains about 37 different columns. What's an efficient way of building out these columns and inserting the data into the temp table.

Comment: I often create a new column the Excel sheet that uses a `CONCAT()` function to create an `INSERT INTO table ...` line, Then I copy that column to a .SQL file and run it in my favorite SQL manger to import the data. Yes, writing the `CONCAT()` function, for 37 columns is a pain, but you only need to write it once.

Comment: Could you give me a quick example of what you mean? For instance, if I have the following columns in excel, how would you put them into the table:

SITEID 
SUBJID 
INITIALS 
DOB 
STATE 
SEX 
RACE
ETH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's say you have an Excel file as follows:

```
    A       B     C        D        E     F   G    H
 1  SITEID SUBJID INITIALS DOB      STATE SEX RACE ETH
 2  123    321    ABC      1/1/2001 CA    M   C    NA
```

The formula to place in column `I` (or after) would be:

`=CONCAT("INSERT INTO temp_db_income (SITEID, SUBJID, INITIALS, DOB, STATE, SEX, RACE, ETH) VALUES (",A2,",",B2,",'",C2,"',",D2,",'",E2,"','",F2,"','",G2,"','",H2,"');")`

This results in a string:

`INSERT INTO temp_db_income (SITEID, SUBJID, INITIALS, DOB, STATE, SEX, RACE, ETH) VALUES (123,321,'ABC',36892,'CA','M','C','NA');`

Note that between each of the column callouts you include either `","` or if the columns have string values `"','"` to delimit the strings in the resulting `CONCAT()`.

While this is a pain the first time you try it, you get the hang of it and you can even cut and paste something like `a2,"','",` a bunch of times, then edit the `a2` to `b2` or `c2` etc. until you have all your 37 columns defined and you removed the `'` marks where not needed. Once you have a `CONCAT` statement that works, you simply copy it to all rows and you are set.

I sometimes use `IF(A2="","",CONCAT("INSERT INTO...)` in order to copy that formula to thousands of rows and have the `INSERT` statement only show up when there's data in the first column of the row.

Comment: awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!